# React-Native IOS build giving error on pod install.?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

Iam new to learning react-native and i want o generate an ios build but it keeps giving me this error whenever i try i run pod install. Iam unable to figure it out where iam wrong i have tried several options but it didnt work. If anyone can tell me where the problem is it would be a great help.

```
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
/Users/shehzad/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/shehzad/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/shehzad/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


[!] `xcodeproj` was renamed to `project`. Please update your Podfile accordingly.

[!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `DC1D7AC84A2642079DCCD9FF` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
```

my pod file

[image: my pod file]

here is my ios project structure

[image: here is my ios project structure]

Comment: seems like you change the name of your podFile, first share with us the podFile definition and a photo of your xcode project open

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eyx6.png @anthonywillismuñoz you can view the ios project structure from her

Comment: I mean a screenshot or lines of your Podfile that is inner ios folder, also a screenshot of the project open in xcode.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTNpG.png here is my pod file

Comment: currently my mac is occupied i will share a screenshot as soon as possible when its freed

Answer (score 2):

comment out flipper command block if you are not using it.

```java
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'studypal' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'studypalTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
end

target 'studypal-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RnDiffApp-tvOS

  target 'studypal-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

then try running pod install again

> cd ios

> pod install

this works for me everytime

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you add xcodeproj property and that is causing the crash. Just rid that line.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'studypal' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'studypalTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'studypal-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RnDiffApp-tvOS

  target 'studypal-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```